# How to merge two Java Classes(Window and Web) into one Java class

Tags: java, selenium, generics

I am doing integration of window to web Application via BDD Framework.I have created two java classes of driver(One for Window and other for Web) having driver reference common for both.

Window class:

```
public class LaunchLogin extends ExecutionerClass {
public static WiniumDriver driver = null;
public static ApplicationPropertiesInitializer applicationProperties = null;
static Properties object,browserLoad = null;
static WebDriverWait wait;
public DesktopOptions options;
public String APP_PATH = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
public String WINIUM_PATH = "http://localhost:9999";

public LaunchLogin() {
    if(driver == null)
    {

        applicationProperties = new ApplicationPropertiesInitializer();

        String objectFileName = "src/test/resources/config/object.properties";
        object = loadPropertiesFile(objectFileName);
    }
}
```

Web Class:

```
public class LaunchLoginWeb extends ExecutionerClass {
public static WebDriver driver = null;
public static ApplicationPropertiesInitializer applicationProperties = null;
static Properties object,browserLoad = null;
public static WebDriverWait wait;

public LaunchLoginWeb() {
    if(driver == null)
    {
        applicationProperties = new ApplicationPropertiesInitializer();
        initilizeBrowser(applicationProperties.getApplicationPropertiesObject().getProperty("browser"));

        String objectFileName = "src/test/resources/config/object.properties";
        object = loadPropertiesFile(objectFileName);
    }
}
```

I have heard with the help of generic,We can club two classes into one Java Class.Can anyone help?

Comment: From a design perspective, what should the relationship between the two classes be? There's some code common to both classes, and you could eliminate this duplication by having one class extend the other, or by moving that code to their common parent `ExecutionerClass`.

Comment: Initialization of driver class is common for both Classes.How can initialize two window(Winium) and Web(Selenium) driver into one class having common reference driver.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `WiniumDriver` implements `WebDriver`, you could factor the common code in a super class and then have 2 child classes.

I think it is a better design than having everything in one class. For example, the Web class has no interest in these variables:

```
public DesktopOptions options;
public String APP_PATH = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
public String WINIUM_PATH = "http://localhost:9999";
```

I would do it this way:

```
public class LaunchLogin extends ExecutionerClass {
  static WebDriver driver = null;
  public static ApplicationPropertiesInitializer applicationProperties = null;
  static Properties object, browserLoad = null;
  static WebDriverWait wait;

  private String objectFileName = "src/test/resources/config/object.properties";

  public LaunchLogin(String type) {
    if(driver == null) {
      applicationProperties = new ApplicationPropertiesInitializer();

      if(type.equals("WEB")) {
        initilizeBrowser(applicationProperties.getApplicationPropertiesObject().getProperty("browser"));
      }
      object = loadPropertiesFile(objectFileName);
    }
  }
}


public class WebLaunchLogin extends LaunchLogin {

  public WebLaunchLogin(String type) {
    super("WEB");
  }

  public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
  }
}

public class WiniumLaunchLogin extends LaunchLogin {
  public DesktopOptions options;
  public String APP_PATH = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
  public String WINIUM_PATH = "http://localhost:9999";

  public WiniumLaunchLogin() {
    super("WINIUM");
  }

  public static WiniumDriver getDriver() {
    return (WiniumDriver)driver;
  }

}
```